# Assign Scriptlet variable to Jsp Textarea

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

```
<% String qDescription = null;

if (questionList == null || questionList.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Empty");
}else{
    System.out.println("Retrieval successful");


        SurveyQuestionBean questionBean= (SurveyQuestionBean)questionList.get(0);
        qDescription = questionBean.getQuestionDescription();
        System.out.println("qDescription HERE: " + qDescription);

}
%>
<td>
    <textarea name="q_description" id="q_description" class="mlselect" cols='100' rows='5' ><%=qDescription%></textarea>
                        </td>
```

I am trying to display the qDescription variable from the Scriptlet to the textarea. The system.out println grabs the correct data, however when i do the assignment it displays null. i understand that Scriptlet is not advisable, but i have to implement it this way. Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: try this `<textarea name="q_description" id="q_description" class="mlselect" cols='100' rows='5' value="${qDescription}" />`

Comment: @M.Sharma thanks for your reply, but upon putting the line of code in the whole page went disorientated.

Comment: @user2505231 i get the data correctly if use your code and hardcode the variable

Comment: disoriented in the sense?

Comment: some textboxes i have in the page went missing, and the alignment of my textarea is off too. @M.Sharma

Comment: Your code for displaying the variable is perfectly fine here can you update the question and tell on sysout what data you are getting?

Comment: Hi @M.Sharma i'm not really familiar with sysout. i did a system.out.println instead (or actually it is the same thing?). i did one in the if else statement, and i added one more just above the textarea control. both prints out "Question 1" (the correct data) in my log. i really cant figure out why it is not working

Comment: It displays `null` because `questionBean.getQuestionDescription()` is returning `null`

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your else clause with a `%>` for jsp page to work properly.

Comment: i am sorry. i did enclosed it, just that i forgot to paste it in too. but it is still not working after checking all the %>, will edit my post now

Answer (score 0):

try this:

<%out.println(qDescription); %>